# Symbolic Mean and Variance Calculations

Tags: summation, distributions, assumptions

I need a tutorial that gets me started on basic symbolic calculations with random variables.  My naive attempts did not get me far.

```
In[1]:= x= NormalDistribution[m,s];

In[2]:= y= NormalDistribution[m,s];

In[3]:= Mean[x+y] // FullSimplify
Out[3]:= Mean[2NormalDistribution[m,s]]
```

I would have expected to see `2*m` here as a result, but this was obviously my fail.

My goal is to be able to evaluate expressions such as `Var[ w_i * R_i ]` and get back `Sum_i[ Sum_j[ 2 * w_i * w_j * Cov[R_i,R_j] ]]`. This means I have to tell Mma that w_i are constant and R_i are random variables.  (In this case, I wouldn't have to tell that the variables are normally distributed, either; just that they are RVs.)  Ideally, I would subsequently be able to tell Mma that `Cov[R_i,R_j]=0` for `i != j` and get back `Sum_i w_i Var[ R_i ]`.

because I often work with repeated draws, being able to specify that all R_i are iid draws from the same distribution would be helpful, too.

Pointers would be highly appreciated.  (As would an example...)

Comment: look up [TransformedDistribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) in the docs. E.g., try `Mean[TransformedDistribution[a + b, {Distributed[a, x], Distributed[b, y]}]]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: great stuff in the TransformedDistribution link (thank you), but not really getting me to where I need to get to---which is manipulation of means and variances.  :-(

Comment: You need to keep the notations for a random variable and a distribution separate.  As such `2*NormalDistribution[m,s]` is not a legitimate command.  If you want to avoid `TransformedDistribution`, consider using `Expectation`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only interested in the means and variances of linear combinations of random variables (where the means, variances, and covariances exist), then consider the following.

Suppose the means and covariances are $\mu$ $\Sigma$, respectively, then the linear combination of the multivariate random variable $X$ and another known vector $\omega$ of the same dimension has mean $$\omega.\mu$$ and the variance is $\omega'.\Sigma.\omega$.  Using *Mathematica* notation:

```
n = 3;
μ = Table[m[i], {i, n}];
Σ = 
  Table[cov[Min[i, j], Max[i, j]], {i, n}, {j, n}] /. 
   cov[i_, i_] -> σ[i]^2;
ω = Table[w[i], {i, n}];

(* Mean of ω.X *)
mean = ω . μ
(* m[1] w[1]+m[2] w[2]+m[3] w[3] *)

(* Variance of ω.X *)
var = ω . Σ . ω // Simplify 
(* 2 cov[1,2] w[1] w[2]+2 cov[1,3] w[1] w[3]+2 cov[2,3] w[2] \
w[3]+w[1]^2 σ[1]^2+w[2]^2 σ[2]^2+w[3]^2 σ[3]^2 *)
```

If you're interested in more complicated functions, please include an example in your question.

**Addition:**

Your example in a comment:

$$Z=\prod _{i=1}^3 (a+b X_i+\epsilon_i)$$

To use replacement rules to determine $E(Z)$ and $Var(Z)$ one could construct the following:

```
z = Product[a + b x[i] + e[i], {i, 3}] // Expand
(* a^3 + a^2 e[1] + a^2 e[2] + a e[1] e[2] + a^2 e[3] + a e[1] e[3] + 
 a e[2] e[3] + e[1] e[2] e[3] + a^2 b x[1] + a b e[2] x[1] + 
 a b e[3] x[1] + b e[2] e[3] x[1] + a^2 b x[2] + a b e[1] x[2] + 
 a b e[3] x[2] + b e[1] e[3] x[2] + a b^2 x[1] x[2] + 
 b^2 e[3] x[1] x[2] + a^2 b x[3] + a b e[1] x[3] + a b e[2] x[3] + 
 b e[1] e[2] x[3] + a b^2 x[1] x[3] + b^2 e[2] x[1] x[3] + 
 a b^2 x[2] x[3] + b^2 e[1] x[2] x[3] + b^3 x[1] x[2] x[3] *)
```

Now assuming that the random variables are all independent of each other the mean of $Z$ is

```
rules = {e[i_]^2 -> σ^2, e[i_] -> 0, x[i_]^2 -> σ[i]^2 + μ[i]^2, x[i_] -> μ[i]};
ez = z /.rules // FullSimplify
(* (a + b μ[1]) (a + b μ[2]) (a + b μ[3]) *)
```

The variance is

```
vz = ((z^2 // Expand) /. rules) - ez^2 // FullSimplify
(* σ^6 + b^2 σ^4 (μ[1]^2 + μ[2]^2 + μ[3]^2 + σ[1]^2 + σ[2]^2 + σ[3]^2) +
   b^4 σ^2 (μ[3]^2 σ[1]^2 + μ[3]^2 σ[2]^2 + σ[1]^2 σ[2]^2 + (σ[1]^2 + σ[2]^2) σ[3]^2 +
   μ[2]^2 (μ[3]^2 + σ[1]^2 + σ[3]^2) + μ[1]^2 (μ[2]^2 + μ[3]^2 + σ[2]^2 + σ[ 3]^2)) + 
   a^4 (3 σ^2 + b^2 (σ[1]^2 + σ[2]^2 + σ[3]^2)) + b^6 ((μ[1]^2 + σ[1]^2) σ[2]^2 (μ[3]^2 + σ[3]^2) +
   μ[2]^2 (μ[3]^2 σ[1]^2 + (μ[1]^2 + σ[1]^2) σ[3]^2)) + 
   2 a^3 (2 b σ^2 (μ[1] + μ[2] + μ[3]) + 
   b^3 (μ[3] (σ[1]^2 + σ[2]^2) + μ[2] (σ[1]^2 + σ[3]^2) + μ[1] (σ[2]^2 + σ[3]^2))) + 
   2 a (b σ^4 (μ[1] + μ[2] + μ[3]) + b^5 (μ[3] (μ[2] (μ[2] + μ[3]) σ[1]^2 + (μ[1] (μ[1] + μ[3]) + 
   σ[1]^2) σ[2]^2) + (μ[2] (μ[1] (μ[1] + μ[2]) + σ[1]^2) + 
   μ[1] σ[2]^2) σ[3]^2) + b^3 σ^2 (μ[2]^2 μ[3] + μ[1]^2 (μ[2] + μ[3]) +
   μ[3] (σ[1]^2 + σ[2]^2) + μ[2] (μ[3]^2 + σ[1]^2 + σ[3]^2) + 
   μ[1] (μ[2]^2 + μ[3]^2 + σ[2]^2 + σ[3]^2))) + 
   a^2 (3 σ^4 + 2 b^2 σ^2 ((μ[1] + μ[2] + μ[3])^2 + σ[1]^2 + σ[2]^2 + σ[3]^2) + 
   b^4 (4 μ[1] μ[3] σ[2]^2 + (μ[1]^2 + σ[1]^2) σ[2]^2 + μ[3]^2 (σ[1]^2 + σ[2]^2) + 
   (μ[1]^2 + σ[1]^2 + σ[2]^2) σ[3]^2 + μ[2]^2 (σ[1]^2 + σ[3]^2) + 
   4 μ[2] (μ[3] σ[1]^2 + μ[1] σ[3]^2))) *)
```

The rules would need to account for any covariances or higher order joint moments which you say you'll add after the expansion.

Comment: Mille grazie.  I need Mma to work with RVs.  indeed, my example was too simple.  let's say I wanted to calculate Var[ \Prod_i[ (a + b*x[i] + e[i]) ] ], and a and b are constants while x[i] and e[i] are RVs .  there will be tons of cross-terms, and Mma will help me not lose them.   I then will want to add assumptions, like all e[i] are iid errors.

Comment: Maybe using replacement rules after expanding to all of the cross-product terms.  I'll add in your product example but I think you're going to have to get used to how *Mathematica* does things (just like any other language).  I would love to have it deal directly with random variables (without having to specify a specific distribution).  But there are folks in this forum far better than me.  So maybe there's hope.

Comment: Thank you.  This goes a very long way towards where I want to go.  It's interesting that Mathematica does not have it "built-in".

Comment: @ivoWelch Do you know of any other software that does have it "built-in" ?  I'd like to use that software.

Comment: me, too.  no, I do not know of any other ones.  incidentally, you have some syntax errors in the rules example.

Comment: @ivoWelch Thanks.  I fixed the errors.  (And I should know better by now not to edit code "to clean it up" without testing it first.  Unfortunately, it probably won't be the last time.)

Comment: @ivoWelch As a statistician the best book and software for mathematical statistics with *Mathematica* is "Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica" at http://mathstatica.com/.  If you're doing lots of statistical manipulations you might want to consider that.  (I have no monetary interest in that software.)

Comment: @ivoWelch Depending on what kinds of things you want (such as expectations of sample moments), the `MomentConvert` and `PowerSymmetricPolynomial` (and others) might be of interest.  See  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/247074/how-to-use-transformeddistribution-to-infer-the-sampling-distribution-of-the-sam