# Adding a new statisitical distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

What would I need to define to add a new statistical distribution to Mathematica?

Ideally, it would support as many of Mathematica's statistical functions as possible.

In practice, this might most easily be done using `ProbabilityDistribution` or `TransformedDistribution` but are there alternatives?

For example, I can give definitions for `unknowndistribution`  (PDF unknown, but specified mean and variance).  For example

```
Mean[unknowndistribution[μ_, σ_]] ^:= μ
Variance[unknowndistribution[μ_, σ_]] ^:= σ^2
```

I then can write

```
d = unknowndistribution[μ, σ];
Mean[d]
(* μ *)
```

but if I try

```
TransformedDistribution[x + y, {x \[Distributed] d, y \[Distributed] d}]
```

it returns effectively unevaluated.

**Motivation**

Some comments have questioned the motivation for doing this.  I'm interested because I want to understand the capabilities of Mathematica.

Clearly, internal distributions are not defined in terms of `ProbabilityDistribution` e.g.

```
ProbabilityDistribution[PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

does not transform automatically to `NormalDistribution[0,1]`.  Internally defined distributions are better supported that those defined via `ProbabilityDistribution`.  It would be interesting to know if it was possible to get some of these additional benefits (without having to add too many definitions).

Doing so is probably hard, but you only establish if a problem is impracticably hard by thinking about and asking other people who probably know far more.

Comment: I'm not following the "why" you want to do this.  I'm not questioning that there is a good reason:  I'm just not understanding.  Would you not need to define all of the desired properties like you did with the mean and variance?  For example: `PDF[unknowndistribution[\[Mu]_, \[Sigma]_], z_] ^:= 
 pdf[z, \[Mu], \[Sigma]]`.

Comment: `ProbabilityDistribution` is the only choice, because `\[Distributed]`, `RandomVariate`, `Expectation` and so on... are not going to work with something else. You'd be writing up-values for everything and it would be grotesquely inefficient.

Comment: I think that the ability to implement new distributions would definitely be very useful. Clearly, there is no documented way to do so, and it's unclear if there is a standardized extension interface even for internal use. If there is one, it is likely in the ``Statistics`Library` `` context. I would start spelunking there.

Comment: @JimB Wouldn't it be great if we could implement our own distributions that work with good performance and good reliability? Sure, `ProbabilityDistribution` allows one to define just about any univariate distribution, but the associated calculations are likely to be slow, unreliable, or entirely infeasible. Wouldn't it be great if we could give pre-calculated formulas for moments, numerical methods for random sampling, explicit formulas or methods for parameter estimation, etc.

Comment: Mathematica could automatically derive operations/formulas which were not explicitly provided, but those that were could be made to be more numerically robust or more performant. (+1 from me, not sure why there was a -1 ...)

Comment: It looks like much of the definition of a distributon is attached to the symbol of that distribution. You can look at the definition of e.g. `ExponentialDistribution`, then make guesses about which of the provided definitions are essential and experiment a bit. Some are certainly necessary for the distribution to be even identified as such.

Comment: I should also say that I am not going to work on an answer. Why? Because I don't see defining your own distribution as being something practical and sustainable. Mathematica's internal workings change constantly. The requirements for a distribution are not only undocumented, but also complex. Whatever I could come up with is likely not to work in all situations and likely break in future versions. For me, it's not worth to spend the considerable amount of the time needed to figure this out if I can't make practical use of it in the future. While it may be fun, I have other hobbies too ;-)

Comment: @Szabolcs  All of what you say makes sense.  Another very recent question is related:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246925/symbolic-mean-and-variance-calculations where something minimal is stated about the probability distribution and just various low order moments - rather than the pdf and cdf - are of interest.