# How can we use TransformedDistribution to infer the sampling distribution of the sample mean?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

As we know, [TransformedDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) can infer a distribution of a transformation like

```
TransformedDistribution[A*X + B, X \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ]]
```

> NormalDistribution[A μ + B, σ Abs[A]]

But can we use it get **the sampling distribution of the sample mean**? Such as $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n \sim \text{NormalDistribution}[μ, σ]$ and then the  $\overline{X}=\frac{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n}{n}\sim \text{NormalDistribution}[μ, σ/\sqrt{n}]$.

Can we do such symbolic derivation? My current try is

```
TransformedDistribution[Mean[{x, y, z}], Table[i \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ], {i, {x, y, z}}]]
```

> NormalDistribution[μ, Abs[σ]/Sqrt[3]]

I have to say it is not a real **symbolic derivation**. I hope to get a $\text{NormalDistribution}[μ, σ/\sqrt{n}]$ result. I am not sure I have missed anything.

---

PS: I mean, I don't want to get the number $3$ in the result. I hope to use $n$ parameters to get $\text{NormalDistribution}[μ, σ/\sqrt{n}]$. The result has that symbol $n$. But I am not sure MMA can do this. Like a real symbolic derivation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** If you do not consider this cheating:

```
TransformedDistribution[w[n] / n, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[μ, σ]]
```

> ```
> NormalDistribution[μ, σ/Sqrt[n]]
> ```

Also

```
SliceDistribution[WienerProcess[μ/n, σ/n], n]
```

> ```
> NormalDistribution[μ, σ/Sqrt[n]]
> ```

and

```
TransformedDistribution[x/n, x \[Distributed] SliceDistribution[WienerProcess[μ, σ], n]]
```

> ```
> NormalDistribution[μ, σ/Sqrt[n]]
> ```

**Original answer:**

```
tdist[n_Integer] := TransformedDistribution[Mean[Array[x, n]], 
      Array[x, n] \[Distributed] ProductDistribution[{NormalDistribution[μ, σ], n}], 
   Assumptions -> {σ > 0}]

tdist /@ Range[4] // Column
```

[image]

```
n = 3;
mnd = MultinormalDistribution[Array[Subscript[μ, #] &, n], 
    Array[Subscript[σ, ##] &, {n, n}]];

TransformedDistribution[Mean[Array[Subscript[x, #] &, n]], 
   Array[Subscript[x, #] &, n] \[Distributed] mnd]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, you just use 3 parameters to get $\text{NormalDistribution}[μ, σ/\sqrt{3}]$. But I hope to use $n$ parameters to get $\text{NormalDistribution}[μ, σ/\sqrt{n}]$

Comment: @yode I don't know if it can be done with symbolic `n`.

Comment: +1 For whatever it's worth, I don't think it's cheating.  Your update seems to me to be the answer.

Comment: Wow, awesome!!, thanks very very much. Can we use your update method to calculate the *The Sampling Distribution of the sample sum-of-squares*? In theory, the result is $χ^2$.

Comment: @yode, I can't think of any way that would work for sample sum-of-squares.

Comment: Stealing from your answer using `TransformedDistribution[Sum[w[i]^2, {i, 1, n}], 
 w \[Distributed] WhiteNoiseProcess[NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]]]]` gives the correct distribution when `n` is defined but gives nothing recognizable for the distribution and the variance is wrong when `n` isn't defined.

Answer (score 4):

This answer also does not use `TransformedDistribution` but does come up with the correct variance and that the distribution is normal using an unspecified sample size.  (My other answer only deals with getting the correct variance.)  But I'm assuming that if `TransformedDistribution` can't be made to work, then you want some method that works for an unspecified sample size.

This solution uses moment generating functions.  (One could also use characteristic functions.)

The moment generating function of a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ is

```
mgf = MomentGeneratingFunction[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], t]
```

$$e^{\frac{\sigma ^2 t^2}{2}+\mu  t}$$

The moment generating function of a sum of normals is found by raising the mgf to the power $n$:

```
mgfSum = mgf^n /. Exp[a_]^n -> Exp[a n] // ExpandAll
```

$$e^{\frac{1}{2} n \sigma ^2 t^2+\mu  n t}$$

Finally get the mgf of the mean which is the sum divided by $n$:

```
mgfxbar = mgfSum /. t -> t/n // ExpandAll
```

$$e^{\frac{\sigma ^2 t^2}{2 n}+\mu  t}$$

Doing all of this in a single command is

```
MomentGeneratingFunction[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], t/n]^n /. Exp[a_]^n -> Exp[a n] // ExpandAll
```

$$e^{\frac{\sigma ^2 t^2}{2 n}+\mu  t}$$

So the sample mean also has a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2/n$ because a moment generating function uniquely identifies the distribution.

Answer (score 3):

The following might be an approach to get moments using an unspecified sample size.  (Admittedly, it's bit circular/odd/obtuse.  I'm sure it can be explained better.)

The sample mean is

```
xbar = Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}]/n
```

This can be represented using the `PowerSymmetricPolynomial` function:

```
xbar = PowerSymmetricPolynomial[1]/n
```

where `PowerSymmetricPolynomial[k]` represents

```
Sum[x[i]^k, {i, 1, n}]
```

If you're willing to allow the expectation of `PowerSymmetricPolynomial[k]` for $k=0,1,2$ to be `n`, `n Moment[1]`, and `n Moment[2]`, respectively, then we write some expectation rules:

```
expectationRules = {PowerSymmetricPolynomial[0] -> n,
  PowerSymmetricPolynomial[1] -> n Moment[1],
  PowerSymmetricPolynomial[2] -> n Moment[2]}
```

We also write some notational rules to put things in customary form:

```
notationRules = {Moment[1] -> μ, Moment[2] -> σ^2 + μ^2, CentralMoment[2] -> σ^2}
```

Putting this altogether using the function `MomentConvert`:

```
Eofxbar = xbar /. expectationRules /. notationRules
(* μ *)

varxbar = MomentConvert[(xbar - Eofxbar)^2, "CentralMoment"] /. expectationRules /. notationRules
(* σ^2/n *)
```

Comment: I recognize I seem to be on a kick of "not answering the direct question."  But It seems the real question is how to get results with an unspecified sample size whether or not `TransformedDistribution` will do the job directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = Element[m, Reals] && s > 0;
```

The distribution of the [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) of `n` i.i.d. normal random variables is

```
dist[n_Integer?Positive] := dist[n] =
  TransformedDistribution[
   Sum[x[k], {k, 1, n}]/n,
   Table[x[k] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[m, s], {k, 1, n}]]
```

The distributions are all normal

```
Union[Head /@ (dist /@ Range[5])]

(* {NormalDistribution} *)
```

The `Mean` is constant

```
μ[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[Mean[dist[#]] & /@ Range[5], n]

(* m *)
```

The [`Variance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variance.html) is

```
var[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[Variance[dist[#]] & /@ Range[5], n]

(* s^2/n *)
```

The [`StandardDeviation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardDeviation.html) is

```
σ[n_] = Sqrt[var[n]] // Simplify

(* Sqrt[1/n] s *)
```

The general result is then

```
NormalDistribution[μ[n], σ[n]]

(* NormalDistribution[m, Sqrt[1/n] s] *)
```

Checking,

```
And @@ Table[dist[n] == NormalDistribution[μ[n], σ[n]], {n, 1, 20}]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand the question, it can be done as follows.

```
Table[TransformedDistribution[Total[Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}]]/n, 
Table[x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], {i, 
1, n}]], {n, 1, 4}]
```

> `{NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]],  NormalDistribution[\[Mu], Abs[\[Sigma]]/Sqrt[2]],  NormalDistribution[\[Mu], Abs[\[Sigma]]/Sqrt[3]],  NormalDistribution[\[Mu], Abs[\[Sigma]]/2]}`

Addition. How about that tricky way (`TransformedDistribution` deals only with concrete sums.)?

```
n = 3; z = TransformedDistribution[Total[Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}]]/n, 
Table[x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], {i, 1, n}]];
Clear[n]; Replace[z, 3 -> n, 3]
```

> `NormalDistribution[\[Mu], Abs[\[Sigma]]/Sqrt[n]]`

Comment: Yes, I have understood it correctly. If my English mislead the topic. Could you help me fix it?

Comment: As your answer, it seems I have misused the 2nd parameter in the `TransformedDistribution`...

Comment: As your answer, it seems I have misused the 2nd parameter in the `TransformedDistribution`. So I have adjusted the question to show my question exactly.

Comment: Hey man, :) I feel crazy to see your newest modify. I don't know why my English so hard to express the real meaning.. You just knock together a $n$ in the result. :)

Comment: @yode: I did my best. Deep regard.

Comment: I really appreciate your attempts. :)

Comment: @yode: The pleasure is mine. Regard again.

Answer (score 1):

**This is doesn't work, but I've not deleted it as I think it's interesting**

You can do a lot of this purely symbolically.  For example, you can define a transformed distribution giving the sum of an arbitrary number of IID random variables (with an arbitrary distribution).

```
\[ScriptD] = 
  TransformedDistribution[1/n Sum[Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, n}], 
   Indexed[x, i] \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]];
```

You can apply `Mean` and `Variance` to this...

```
{Mean[\[ScriptD]], Variance[\[ScriptD]]};
```

... but it doesn't do anything useful, until you substitute a specific distribution...

```
{Mean[\[ScriptD]], 
  Variance[\[ScriptD]]} /. {{\[ScriptCapitalD] -> 
    NormalDistribution[μ, σ]}, {\[ScriptCapitalD] -> 
    ExponentialDistribution[1/μ]}}
(* {{μ, σ^2}, {μ, μ^2}} *)
```

And as you wished, substituting specific distributions give the distributions of the sample mean

```
\[ScriptD] /. {{\[ScriptCapitalD] -> 
     NormalDistribution[μ, σ]}, {\[ScriptCapitalD] -> 
     ExponentialDistribution[1/μ]}} // FullSimplify
(* {NormalDistribution[μ, σ], 
 ExponentialDistribution[1/μ]} *)
```

**Unfortunately, as you'll note the answers are wrong.  It assumes that all the `Indexed[x,i]` are the same value**